Should coffee machines be deconcentrated?
We model some region by convex and compact $E\subset \mathbb R^2$. $N\ge 1$ coffee machines are provided for the people living on $E$, of capacities $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_N>0$. Assume the population of $E$ is uniformly distributed such that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n = \ell(E),$$
where $\ell$ is the Lebesgue measure. If locating the machines at $x_1,\ldots, x_N\in E$ with $X:=(x_1,\ldots, x_N)$, the transportation cost is given as
$$F(X):=W_2(\mu_X,\ell) \quad\mbox{with}\quad \mu_X:=\sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_n\delta_{x_n}, \quad\quad  \forall X\in E^N,$$
where $W_2$ denotes the Wasserstein metric of order $2$. As $F:E^N\to\mathbb R_+$ is Lipschitz and $E^N$ is compact, its minimum is attained. Can we find a minimiser $X^*=(x_1^*,\ldots, x_N^*)\in E^N$ for $F$ such that $x^*_m\neq x^*_n$ for all $m\neq n$?

Do you know of a situation where a minimiser $(x_1^, \dots, x_N^)$ with $x_n^* = x_m^*$ for $n \neq m$ exists? I thought I had an argument that this is impossible.

Do you have response to the answer below? :)

Disclaimer: I'm not confident about this argument because of the way you framed your question and me being not an expert on any of the involved objects. I hope someone can confirm this or correct me.
Let $X = (x_1,\ldots, x_N)$ be a minimiser.
Then $W_2(\mu_{X},\ell)^2 = \int_{E} \, \vert x - T(x) \vert^2 \, \mathrm{d}x$ for a map $T$ such that $\mu_{X} = \ell \circ T^{-1}$.
Let $\hat{A}_j := \{T = x_j\}$ for $j \in \{1, \dots, N\}$.
The $\hat{A}_j$ may not be disjoint, when $x_i = x_j$ for $i \neq j$ or because they could agree on sets of Lebesgue measure zero.
But we can select disjoint $A_1, \dots, A_n$ such that $\ell(A_j) = \alpha_j$ and $A_j \subseteq \{T = x_j\}$, by throwing away duplicates and then decomposing the kept $\hat{A}_j$ in pieces of the right Lebesgue measure and also throwing away Lebesgue measure zero intersections.
Then
$$W_2(\mu_{X},\ell)^2 
= \int_{E} \, \vert x - T(x) \vert^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{E} \, \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \vert x - T(x) \vert^2 \, \mathbb{1}_{A_j} \, \mathrm{d}x\\
=  \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \int_{E} \,\vert x - T(x) \vert^2 \, \mathbb{1}_{A_j} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \int_{A_j} \, \vert x - x_j \vert^2.$$.
But the term $\sum_{j = 1}^{N} \int_{A_j} \, \vert x - x_j \vert^2$ is minimised for fixed $A_1, \dots, A_n$ iff each $x_j$ is the centroid of $A_j$.
Here centroid is meant as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#By_integral_formula.
That means that the $x_j$ really have to be the centroids $\tilde{x}_j$ of the $A_j$, because otherwise
$$
W_2(\mu_{\tilde{X}}, \ell)^2 \leq \int_{E} \, \vert x - \tilde{T}(x) \vert^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \int_{A_j} \, \vert x - \tilde{x}_j \vert^2
< \sum_{j = 1}^{N} \int_{A_j} \, \vert x - x_j \vert^2
= W_2(\mu_{X},\ell)^2 
$$ for $\tilde{X} = (\tilde{X}_1, \dots, \tilde{X}_n)$ and $\tilde{T} = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \tilde{x}_j \mathbb{1}_{A_j}$, hence $X$ wouldn't have been a minimiser.
Now suppose $x_1 = x_2$.
Then $A_1$ and $A_2$ and also $A_1 \cup A_2$ have the same centroid $x_1 = x_2$.
We now just need to decompose $A_1 \cup A_2$ into $\tilde{A}_1$ and $\tilde{A}_2$ with $\ell(\tilde{A}_1) = \alpha_1, \ell(\tilde{A}_2) = \alpha_2$ but different centroids, because then $$\int_{\tilde{A}_1} \, \vert x - \tilde{x}_1 \vert^2 + \int_{\tilde{A}_2} \, \vert x - \tilde{x}_2 \vert^2 < \int_{\tilde{A}_1} \, \vert x - x_1 \vert^2 + \int_{\tilde{A}_2} \, \vert x - x_2 \vert^2 = \int_{A_1 \cup A_2} \vert x - x_1 \vert^2 = \int_{A_1} \, \vert x - x_1 \vert^2 + \int_{A_2} \, \vert x - x_2 \vert^2,$$ which again cannot be the case if $X$ actually is a minimiser.
But this recomposition of $A_1 \cup A_2$ into $\tilde{A}_1 \cup \tilde{A}_2$ should be possible by for example intersecting with a half-plane.

Thanks unwissen for the response and sorry for the late reply as I was in travel. Your reasoning seems to be the right one for me, while it is not 100% rigorous for me. Namely, for

"Now suppose $x_1 = x_2$.
Then $A_1$ and $A_2$ and also $A_1 \cup A_2$ have the same centroid $x_1 = x_2$." Note that when $x_1$ coincides with $x_2$, how could you identify the regions $A_1, A_2$? For such a case there is a single partition corresponding to $x_1=X_2$. Could you please explain more for this?

@Fawen90 I don't really get your doubt about rigour , therefore I tried to add some details to the explanation. Please ask again if this doesn't resolve the issue you are seeing!

Thanks for the quick reply. What I'm saying is that, when you assume $x_1=x_2$, you can not define $A_1$ and $A_2$ that correspond to your optimal transport plan. Your arguments above make sens only for the case for $x_1,\ldots, x_N$ are mutually distinct

@Fawen90 I think I explained that in the edited version now, but maybe in a little more detail how this is possible: Suppose for simplicity of notation $x_1 = x_2$, but $x_j \neq x_1$ for $j \in {3, \dots, N}$. Then the optimal transport plan $T$ satisfies $\ell({T = x_1}) = \mu_X({x_1}) = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$. So just cut ${T = x_1}$ into two disjoint pieces $A_1, A_2$ which each obey $\ell(A_1) = \alpha_1$ and $\ell(A_2) = \alpha_2$.

@Fawen90 But this is really not the main point, I just wrote it down with the disjoint $A_j$ instead working with ${T = x_j}$ to have simpler notation. The actual argument is that if $x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_k$, then you always get a smaller Wasserstein distance if you cut up the corresponding region ${T = x_1} = ... = {T = x_k}$ in $k$ pieces with the right Lebesgue measure and let $\tilde{x}_1, \dots, \tilde{x}_k$ be the centroids of these new pieces.
